# Where should compounds be built for an impending "zombie" apocalypse?

Tags: science-based, apocalypse, construction, logistics

I have been working on a post-apocalypse world where over 90% of the world’s population died in a “zombie” apocalypse (technically living zombie trope). This apocalypse occurred around 125 years prior. The world has recovered with technology roughly resembling that of the mid-20th century. However, there are pockets of population living in what are called enclaves.

These enclaves, unlike the rest of the world, are technologically more advanced. The technology and culture in these enclaves resemble that of cyberpunk. The only reason these enclaves have any power over the rest of the world is due to their technological superiority.

What I am trying to figure out is where these enclaves be located and other aspects concerning their construction. For the time being, I am concentrating on the ones in the former United States. The following are some of the events leading up to their construction.

- “Evil” genetic engineering corporation was researching a virus with possible military applications on a remote North Pacific Island. This facility was unknown to exist.
- A cyclone damaged this research facility which cause the virus to escape containment. “Evil”    corporation predicted pandemic in 5 – 10 years (in practice, it was 20) and they secretly informed key governments of what happened and the nature of the virus. In other words, some governments knew what was coming and a rough idea of when.
- The nature of the virus is that it causes violent behavior in infected individuals against both infected and uninfected. The virus is spread through contact with an infected individual and could take a 7-10 days for symptoms. There are going to be few roaming hoards; mostly wandering individuals (this behavior was not expected).
- In the United States government, only the president and a select few members of Congress knew of the impending pandemic.
- A clandestine committee commissioned the construction of the enclaves to shelter friends and family of US government officials and key business leaders.

My initial thoughts were that these enclaves would be located near major population centers such as New York City, Chicago, Portland, Denver, and Las Vegas but that idea falls apart for obvious reasons. I was thinking that the enclaves would be scatted as the main justification to the public was to house people after natural disasters. One idea I considered was that the early enclaves were built with something resembling a FEMA trailer made from shipping containers.

Other considerations that I can think of:

- The construction of these enclaves must use existing technologies and industries and is limited to what is available today (groundbreaking of the first one is 2032).
  They need to be easily defended requiring the minimal resources which points to away from major population centers.
- They need to be self-sufficient and capable of becoming self-sufficient before supplies run out.
- Land acquisition is going to be a major barrier. However, the president (and successor) will be willing to use extra-Constitutional means.
- Ownership of the land was transferred to the single developer of the enclaves (this is a key point that drives conflict between the enclaves and the US government).
- The true purpose of the enclaves must remain in secrecy as possible but eventually the public will start asking questions.
- Things should be hard science fiction as much as possible. There are some fantastical elements, but they are tangential.

Should these enclaves scatted throughout the United States, or does it make more sense to have them clustered in one or two states? What terrain would be best for them?

Comment: Where you put them depends quite strongly on the details of the zombies. For example:  Are they defeated by a 50 foot cliff? Some kind of mountain location with a nice flat wall already built in might be the thing. They won't cross water? Then some kind of island. Whatever stops or deters them, that should be readily and abundantly available.

Comment: And, by the way, that is also a big possible source of drama and conflict. Oh, it's an island in a big river, and the Zs won't cross water? Well it has not rained for five weeks and the water level is dropping. You get the idea.

Comment: Yes, the nature of the zombies would be important and I completely forgot to add that. I'll edit my question to include that. As for them, the initial variants of the virus cause violent behavior toward infected and uninfected alike.

Comment: What is the infection mechanism? I presume that physical contact with a zombie is not the only one.

Comment: It would be mostly airborne transmission but physical contact can result in infection especially if there a break in the skin.

Comment: what is the population of these enclaves? Also define "self sufficient", they will not be able to maintain current technology in isolation.

Comment: Where ever it is, it needs to be near a supply of freshwater (lake, river, etc.) and be next to enough arable land to supply the enclave with produce and livestock. As for being self-sufficient, John has it right: where is this enclave going to get all the natural resources (metal ores, minerals, chemicals, etc) to be self sufficient?  Where is it going to place all the necessary processing facilities (smelters, refineries, chemical plants, etc.) let along find the personnel to operate them?  How is it going to power all this without a large nuclear power plant (which itself needs mined fuel)?

Comment: "The groundbreaking [...] must use existing technologies", what are the existing technologies in 2032?

Comment: One key metric you have provided. How long do your 'zombies' survive post infection? That lets you estimate how long your compounds have to be self sufficient for. If for example the average infected person dies of malnutrition/exposure etc after a couple of months because they have lost the ability to feed or care for themselves then plague will burn itself out in a couple of years.

Comment: It also feeds into what the government should do. They might for instance choose to close down key facilities, factories and power plants etc secure fuel and food depots and mothball planes, trains, trucks and ships in the knowledge that they can all be reactivated once the plague has burnt itself out.

Comment: How is the virus not an issue for 20 years if it's in the wild and airborne? Does it not infect humans, and they're preparing for it to mutate?

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan You are right and they did run into those problems. They did have to build additional enclaves after the pandemic as well as recruit labor from the survivors. My thoughts on that was that they preserved the knowledge and as many tools as possible which gave them an advantage.

Comment: @Mon Assuming the zombies do not meet a violent end, the most common cause of death will be exposure and starvation.

Comment: @MatthewWells I was thinking that it is a combination of the model being incorrect and the corporation taking active measures to keep it from leaving the island. What I was going for here is events go from "we're all going to die" to "I guess we dodged that bullet" to "oh no, it is really happening." Do you think that 20 years is too long for it to finally cross over to humans from primates and escape the island?

Comment: @MichaelKilgore I don't think predicting a mutation in 10 years is too strange, but it only escaping the island when it jumps to humans is too strange- why wouldn't the corporation firebomb the island after preliminary containment? It'd be simpler if doesn't present full symptoms in non-humans and makes it to the mainland before they catch it. At that point, it might be too late to stop it from spreading and eventually mutating.

Comment: Michael, if you go to the Science Stack excahnge forum there will likely be someone with a knowledge of epidemiology or medicine who can help you calculate how long the plague would take to burn itself out. Theres a relativly simple forula where if you plug in the average number of days after infention before someone becomes infectious, an estimate (on average) of how many people that person will infect on a daily basis and how long before (again on average) they die then that gives you an aproximate time period (In this case probably a cuople of years) before the plague will end.

Answer (score 4):

### Military Bases:

So you need a place, not too far from the folks you are evacuating. You need it to be armed to the teeth, well equipped to fend off attacks, and well equipped with specialty buildings with air filtration and biohazard suits. You need it to be ready in 5-10 years (although they ended up having longer than anticipated) so pre-existing facilities will work best. They should be set up to be high-tech preserves. You want to be able to horde vast quantities of supplies and possibly greenhouses/agricultural facilities to sustain your groups living there. Finally, you want to be able to have all these preparations be invisible to the general public, so they need to have all this activity be completely explainable.

By definition, military bases are located in relatively strategic locations. The government already owns the land, so building anything on it is problem-free. Eminent domain used to expand such facilities could be justified as creating a secure buffer zone to protect them from terrorism. Using that buffer zone for agriculture is just being good stewards of the resources acquired (as well as guaranteeing the bases a food supply in the event of a major disaster). Existing buildings on the land are converted into enclave facilities.

Any unusual fortifications you build around a military base can get sunk into the vast military budget. Huge bunker systems make perfect sense (they may even be pre-existing). These are already the places that will have NBC equipment to protect them and their inhabitants from contagion. Further, you have a ready-made security force highly motivated and well-equipped to defend the facility from ravening zombies. The existence of the enclaves as a separate thing might never even be realized by the general public. After all, it just shows the government anticipated a potential threat and prepared their facilities against it.

You will need to do some interesting social gymnastics to explain why the US government would then sell these military bases to a private individual. With the mention of eminent domain, the land could be taken by the government, then (when it looked like the contagion wasn't going to happen after 10 years) the government sells all the "useless" facilities around the military bases to the developer who built them, to be used to develop universities, defense manufacturing and research facilities (like a land grant). The developer knows about and still believes in the upcoming apocalypse, and works to save the people he/she deems worth saving (by attracting them to live & work in their newly acquired facilities).

Each enclave would thus be defended by the military (next door), built and equipped by the military, a haven for knowledge & high-tech manufacturing, yet no longer under the control of the government. The enclaves might even be able to make the military indebted to them by supplying the bases with the goods they need to stay alive. With all the effort lavished by the government on these enclaves, you could see why the government might resent the enclaves (especially if the enclaves didn't let all the government fat-cats in after the apocalypse started; after all, they decided there was no threat...)

Comment: Actually, this is quite possibly the best answer to this question. Any governmental zombie-apocalypse plan that does not concern the military isn't going to work by any means, as having weapons does not mean one can use them effectively.

Comment: Re: "By definition, military bases are located in relatively strategic locations.", I think you would be hard pressed to say that any particular military base was sited to protect anything in immediate proximity or was designed to be defensible other than in a historical sense; they're not near mines, factories, or anything else usually.  As for sneaking in "unusual fortifications", modern warfare is maneuver warfare using mechanized units; building something around a military designed to defend against zombies would really raise eyebrows among the troops and be impossible to keep secret.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Given the changing modern situation, anti-riot walls constructed around facilities and networks of fencing don't seem all that implausible. They threw up similar barriers around the capitol building, and even here in Minnesota, riot barriers were put up around the state capitol. Given riots, COVID, and terrorism, you could have quite a network. For that matter, ring the whole thing in a major highway with "sound abatement" walls and it will look an awful lot like a fortress, ready-made kill zone included.

Answer (score 3):

**Islands.**

Because all the enclaves are actually Singaporean colonies.  Singapore already had the advanced tech when the apocalypse happened, and the rapid reflexes of the government saved their island state from the zombies.

Now they are colonizing the rest of the world.  The current enclaves all date from the decades after the apocalypse as forces based in Singapore moved out, clearing new islands to use as bases.   Because part of their salvation was being on an island that has become a strong piece of the cultural identity of their descendants.  Island enclaves in other countries are fortified against zombies but also the nonzombie residents of the area.

Answer (score 3):

Going much beyond mid-20th century tech requires a **global** scale. Count the number of airliner manufacturers in the Western world. The number of CPU production lines. A relatively small enclave cannot really afford them. You will need some **handwaving** to explain that away, and the handwaving might dictate your enclaves, which form a network.

- Around the mines for rare eath metals for batteries.
- Around a nuclear power station or an oil refinery.
- Around an university campus with a prototype-scale microchip fabricator.
- Around a state-of-the-art factory for 3D printers.

Comment: **handwawing**...

Comment: @AlexanderNied, fixed. I posted at 0-dark-30, or what would have been a dark time in another season.

Comment: You are right about the handwaving which is one of the key reasons that the pandemic happens 125 years in the past. The assumption I am making that even though technology is lost the knowledge that they archived (and tools preserved) is enough to springboard them into a new information age in that time.

Answer (score 2):

Zombies are basically a primitive army with little need for supplies (although this goes against basic biology, but then, so does zombiness). They have a source of rough building materials in themselves, so they can fill ditches and build ramps.

What deters them is a vertical slope taller than they can build a ramp out of themselves before collapsing (10-12 mt, tops, unless you have *millions* of zombies available), or an unfillable ditch (because there is e.g. a river at the bottom that will float corpses away).

It is possible to incorporate one or both features in almost any secluded tourist resort, military base, and so on.

Other things that may stop zombies:

- cold. Build the enclave somewhere high and way north.
- heat. Build the enclave in the middle of Death Valley (but I don't know what happens there in winter).
- distance. They have no reason to wander in large masses patrolling the world, so you can hide out of the way and kill the few zombies that wander into the exclusion zone.
- distractions. Every time a zombie negotiates the pass that would lead into Forbidden Valley, they hear screams from a nearby cave. When they scramble to the cave, the screams start coming from a cave opposite. Zombies do not have the smarts to grok photodetectors and solar-powered concealed loudspeakers, so they'll start ping-ponging between several caves, reasonably exhausting themselves sooner or later. With some foresight and engineering, they could be hijacked into a, hopefully non-renewable, energy source.